# How can I set a new column in a table based on the rank of other columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression, rank, sql-update

I have a Microsoft SQL Server table that has two columns in it - one for *Locations* and one for associated *Images*. Up until now, **multiple** images could be associated with the same location and only the **last** uploaded image was actually used by on the mobile site. This was achieved by assigning an *ImageRank* to each row:

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY Image DESC) ImageRank
```

so that only rows with ImageRank = 1 were picked up by an SSIS process which dealt with the mobile Site:

Now we want to be able to **pick** which of the **existing** images (not just the last one) to display. For that purpose we introduced a third column - **MobileSelection** of type bit. Since this column was introduced late it has Nulls for all of the existing rows.

So I have something like this:

```
+-------+----------+-----------------+-----------+
| image | location | MobileSelection | ImageRank |
+-------+----------+-----------------+-----------+
|   850 |       10 |         NULL    |         1 |
|   209 |       10 |         NULL    |         2 |
+-------+----------+-----------------+-----------+
```

And I want to set only the row with ImageRank of 1 to 1. Keep in mind that ImageRank is not an actual column otherwise this would be trivial.

My goal is to be able to write an update statement which would assign a value of 1 to this column if the row it is on has an calculated ImageRank of 1. The issue I am running into is being able to combine the Rank Over Partition (or something similar) clause with the Update statement:

```
UPDATE dining_location SET MobileSelection = 1 WHERE RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY Image DESC) = 1;
```

The above returns this error:

Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

I would appreciate any help with this. Thank you!

Comment: My bad. I should have been more specific. The error I get is "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.". This is the first time I ran into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is to update mobileselection = 1 for latest images of each location.

You can use below SQL -

```
UPDATE dining_location SET MobileSelection = 1 
WHERE image in (select t.image from 
(select location, image, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY Image DESC) as rrank from dining_location) t where t.rrank = 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am getting Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'. I think there may have been an extra closing parentheses at the end, too. Any suggestions?

Comment: there was an extra ')' at the end. i fixed it. pls check now.

Comment: Thanks again. I did remove the extra ')' and I am getting 'Incorrect syntax near the 'where'. Expecting AS, ID, or QUOTED_ID.

This is happening right at the very last part on  WHERE rrank = 1

Comment: this query runs without 'AS' in Oracle. I just realized you need it for sql server. Try with 'AS'.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried it with AS and got the same result. Based on what I am seeing this may have to do with the format of the IN clause.

Comment: I have given alias to inner select statement also. Please try the updated SQL now. I dont see any other possibility of error with IN clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use an updatable CTE:

```
WITH toupdate as (
      SELECT dl.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY Image DESC) as seqnum
      FROM dining_location dl
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET MobileSelection = 1
    WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. Can you please explain what dl.* is?

I get the following errors:

The column prefix 'dl' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

No column name was specified for column 1 of 'toupdate'.

Comment: Update: I changed dl.* to * and it appears to have worked. Checking the results now